# how to get the MAX() from a SUM() subquery in SQL

Tags: mysql, sum, max

I have a table from where I need to calculate the sum of some values and then take the max value of each sum.
The code that I have is the below:

```
SELECT q1.prod_code, q1.cust_code, MAX(q1.total_sum) 
FROM (SELECT k2.prod_code, k2.cust_code, SUM(k2.price) AS total_sum FROM reservation AS k2 GROUP BY k2.prod_code, k2.cust_code) AS q1 
GROUP BY q1.prod_code
```

From the above I get almost the correct result.
I had to get:

prod_code | cust_code | total_sum
  1001    |  10002    |   75
  1002    |  10005    |  209
  1003    |  10005    |  350
  1004    |  10002    |  650

But instead of this I get:

prod_code | cust_code | total_sum
  1001    |  10001    |   75
  1002    |  10001    |  209
  1003    |  10003    |  350
  1004    |  10001    |  650

Actually the cust_code are the first values in the subquery for each separate prod_code.

Do you have any idea what might be wrong?

Comment: I believe your issue is with your outer `group by`.  `Mysql` allows this, but most other databases do not.  It's basically returning a random `cust_code`.  You need to join back to the same query to get the correct one.

Comment: This might be, but how to join the sub query with the external one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, `mysql` allows you to leave out non-aggregated fields from the `group by` clause.  In doing so, you cannot guarantee the result for those omitted values.

To resolve your problem you need to `join` the combined query back to the original query.  While not very pretty using multiple aggregates, something like this should work:

```
SELECT t1.prod_code, t2.cust_code, t1.max_total_sum
FROM (
    SELECT prod_code, MAX(total_sum) max_total_sum
    FROM (
        SELECT prod_code, cust_code, SUM(price) AS total_sum 
        FROM reservation
        GROUP BY prod_code, cust_code) AS q1 
    GROUP BY prod_code
) t1 JOIN (
   SELECT prod_code, cust_code, SUM(price) AS total_sum 
   FROM reservation
   GROUP BY prod_code, cust_code) AS t2 ON t1.prod_code = t2.prod_code
       AND t1.max_total_sum = t2.total_sum
```

Comment: @ToroLoco -- I haven't tested this.  Looks like I had the sums backwards which I just edited.  Not sure why prod_code wouldn't work though.

Comment: Somehow mysql don't see the sub query attributes outside of it.

Comment: ok it worked now after I changed the sums. Thank you very much.